# How do you define where your app.config file is to read it?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, app-config

I have added an app.config file to my application. How can I defien where the app.config file is so that I can read it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to be read by the built-in configuration system, `app.config` should be located in the same directory as the executable using it.

*However*, it must *not* be named `app.config`. It should be named `program_name.exe.config`, where program_name is the name of the exe file.

So, if you have `myprogram.exe`, your config file needs to be `myprogram.exe.config`

If you are using Visual Studio, it does this for you as part of the build process. You edit the file as `app.config` within the IDE, and the normal build process will copy it and rename it to match the exe output for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is little bit not clear.When you deploy your .Net application, the app.config  file  will come with exe name.You need to use System.Configuration namespace to use app .config in your code

```
use System.Configuration;

................
..................
......... 
var x=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["name"];
```

The ConfigurationManager automatically read that exe app config file..

Comment: Pretty much correct, except that you should not use the code here to extract the value. `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[]` is going to return a `string` value already, and tacking on a `ToString()` call does nothing but risk a `NullReferenceException` if the value is not set.

Comment: ya your are correct.I changed my cording.No need to put toString().